# Import StartCom CA certificates in Windows JRE

Tags: java, security, certificate, keystore, truststore

I have a Java application accessing a service that uses a StartCom SSL certificate. For this to work, I need to add the StartCom CA certs to Java's truststore, because they're not in there by default yet. I've succesfully done that on linux using these commands

```
sudo keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias startcom.ca -file ca.crt
sudo keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias startcom.ca.sub.class1 -file sub.class1.server.ca.crt
sudo keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias startcom.ca.sub.class2 -file sub.class2.server.ca.crt
sudo keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias startcom.ca.sub.class3 -file sub.class3.server.ca.crt
sudo keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias startcom.ca.sub.class4 -file sub.class4.server.ca.crt
```

(From [this script](http://www.ailis.de/~k/uploads/scripts/import-startssl))

The same command (adapted appropriately) doesn't work on Windows however. I get:

```
keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage error, trustcacerts is not a legal command
```

How to make it work?

Comment: hi i'm still getting the error..
how to solve it. Harsh Raval.

Comment: You forget to mention that more often than not you have two Java key stores on Windows: one for the JDK and another for the public JRE under `C:\Program Files`. In this case you have add the certs to both stores.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a simple typo. In converting the command I forgot a dash before "trustcacerts". :(

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS X Mavericks 10.9 I did this:

I always make a tmp directory that I delete later, but you don’t have to:

```
mkdir ~/tmp
cd ~/tmp
```

Then download the certs:

```
curl http://www.startssl.com/certs/ca.crt -O
curl http://www.startssl.com/certs/sub.class1.server.ca.crt -O
curl http://www.startssl.com/certs/sub.class2.server.ca.crt -O
curl http://www.startssl.com/certs/sub.class3.server.ca.crt -O
curl http://www.startssl.com/certs/sub.class4.server.ca.crt -O
```

Get your Java home:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Use keytool to install it:

```
sudo keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/securitycacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias startcom.ca -file ca.crt

sudo keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias startcom.ca.sub.class1 -file sub.class1.server.ca.crt

sudo keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/securitycacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias startcom.ca.sub.class2 -file sub.class2.server.ca.crt

sudo keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/securitycacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias startcom.ca.sub.class3 -file sub.class3.server.ca.crt

sudo keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/securitycacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias startcom.ca.sub.class4 -file sub.class4.server.ca.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove -trustcacerts

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `-trustcacerts` is the right syntax.

But for the linked script to work under Cygwin you need to remove `sudo` from all `keytool` lines - `sudo` is unavailable in Cygwin.