# Java HttpsURLConnection SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, https, http-put, sslhandshakeexception

I am attempting to make a HTTPS connection to a website using `HttpsURLConnection`, and then perform a PUT request. When I try to create the `OutputStreamWriter` from `HttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream()`, the following exception is thrown:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

The page has just gotten its certificate (issued by StartCom) - do I need to manually do something to make Java recognise the certificate is present now? I can connect to other pages of the same website with no difficulty, but they have a different certificate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can import the root certificate of StartCom yia the tool keytool (from JDK) into a Java Key Store (JKS) and then set the key store as "trusted store".

See section "Exporting and Importing Certificates" on:

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/secureinternet2/

Commands mentioned in that article:

Import certifificate to trustedcerts.jks:

```
keytool -import -keystore trustedcerts.jks -alias qusay -file server.crt
```

Start Java using custom tuststore:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=trustedcerts.jks com.example.MyClass
```

Alternatively you can set the truststore at runtime:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","./trustedcerts.jks");
```

Comment: Thanks - for anyone else with the same issue, I saved the certificate locally, used the `keytool -import ...` command and added `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "path_to_keystore");` to my code.

Answer (score 0):

Please also see this question: [Import StartCom CA certificates in Windows JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4302686/162522)

It links to a script for importing StartCom certificates into your JDK trusted store.